# A package to replace H2O's `h2o.word2vec` function?

Tags: r, text-mining, word2vec, h2o, word-embedding

I am successfully using `h2o.word2vec` function to load pre-trained GloVe embeddings in R.

`embed_model <- h2o.word2vec(pre_trained = glove, vec_size = 300)
df_doc_vecs <- h2o.transform(embed_model, tokenized_words, aggregate_method = "AVERAGE")`

However, because my production environment will not support H2O, I need to find another package with similar functionality. Specifically I just need to be able to replace `h2o.word2vec` and `h2o.transform` with something else to:

[1] Use GloVe or any other pre-trained embeddings

[2] Create sentence or document level vectors out of them

Any suggestions? Has to be in R...

Comment: P.S.: To be honest, I don't understand what h2o.word2vec does and why do I need a model at all, if the task is to average vectors. It's been handy because the output model's size is smaller than GloVe embeddings file. And maybe it should be renamed, because technically if I'm using non-word2vec embeddings, it's not word2vec method anymore.

Comment: I'm curious why your prod environment can't support H2O, is that something we can help you fix?

Comment: @ErinLeDell Thanks for the offer.  I do appreciate H2O, but this is going to be a program that has to run on hundreds of laptops under different versions of mac OS and Windows. The issues around installing dev Java environments on these vastly different machines are overwhelming for a singlehandedly developed product. And I'm only using H2O for this one step. So it makes sense to find a workaround in this case.

Comment: Makes sense!  We would encourage you to use Docker in this case, but it's probably easier to swap to another tool, as you said.